# Async FB request with block in separated thread issue

Tags: ios, facebook, multithreading, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I'm working with the IOS Facebook SDK 3, and I'm trying to use it with the more efficient approach.
So I would like to manage some requests in separate threads.

**For example this request (WORKS PERFECTLY) :**

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    [self generateShareContentFor:ShareServiceTypeFacebook 
                         callback:^(NSMutableDictionary* obj)
     {
         FBRequest * rq = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                                               parameters:obj 
                                               HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
         [rq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { 

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 // TREATING RESULT
                 [[UFBManager defaultManager] errorHandlerFromError:error 
                                                         fromRqType:UFBManagerRqTypePost];
              });

          }];
     }];  

});
```

- I'm using this one to post something on my feed, I call a method to load the content of this request automatically and then this block will be called in the method to launch the request.
  This one works well.
- The problem is if I don't put this request inside a block, that doesn't work.

**This request doesn't work**

```
     dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
     dispatch_async(queue, ^{

          FBRequest * rq = [FBRequest requestForMe];
          [rq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    // TREATING RESULT
                    [[UFBManager defaultManager] errorHandlerFromError:error 
                                                          fromRqType:UFBManagerRqTypeGet];

                  });

          }];
     });
```

I'm trying to figure out, but I don't understand what is the problem.
Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more information. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christopher, and sorry for the lack of information. When I try to debug this second request, I can log until the *rq declaration, but I don't have any coming back of the block of completion handler declared while starting the startCompletionHandler method

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem for a bit.

Make sure you dispatch the code on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{

           FBRequest * rq = [FBRequest requestForMe];
           [rq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                   //The docs say this will be the main queue here anyway
                   //Feel free to go on a background thread at this point
                   }];

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive why it works in one case and not the other, but I think it has to do with the run loop for your background queue not running after `startWithCompletionHandler:` returns.

But I wonder why you're putting that on a background queue anyways, since it's an asynchronous call. Why not just do this from the main thread:

```
FBRequest * rq = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[rq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UFBManager defaultManager] errorHandlerFromError:error 
                                              fromRqType:UFBManagerRqTypeGet];
      });
}];
```

Comment: The problem in my case is that the main thread is already occupied by other things and my goal is to load the list of your Facebook friend in a different thread to don't heavier burdening the main one

Comment: I see, it looks like `FBURLConnection` just runs an NSURLConnection on the thread it was invoked from. I would have thought it would run the network connection on a background thread. Otherwise, why expose an async API?

Comment: Yes that's true, I didn't think about it and it seems logical, so what should I do is treat, for example my list of 5000 friends, in a second thread. Because this callback : `startWithCompletionHandler:` is executed in the main queue so the list treatment will be dispatched from this main queue ? Do I have a correct approach ?

Comment: I filed a bug report on Facebook Developer for something really similar: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/551787081506376

Comment: any resolution on this? I'm having the same problem. FB seems to have closed this bug without fixing.